# Session won't start and server variables are incorrect

Tags: php, http

I am trying to start session this way:

```
session.auto_start = 1
```

I set it this way. The session doesn't start. I changed start in my php as the following:

```
ini_set("session.use_only_cookies",true); 
session_save_path(dirname(__file__)."/../User");
```

Basically, I dont see any file created in that folder.

Also when I do this:

```
$id=session_id();
```

I get `$id=0;`

Why all those mistakes happen?

Comment: Have you tried checking your php error log? It might contain info about what's going wrong, such as file access errors etc.

Comment: hmmm. I wonder how to do that... The session itself does start automatically cause I get no mistakes... But the session id is 0 each time :(

Comment: That User Agent just looks like Chrome to me. Did you call session_start() in your php script?

Comment: no, I set it in the php as I updated above.. The session doesnt start. please help me to understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to start session this way:
>
> session.auto_start()

Where and how do you do that? Not in code I hope? It's a [php.ini setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start), and if you want to enable it, you have to do it there.

> I changes start in my php as the following:
>
> ```
>   ini_set("session.use_only_cookies",true); 
>   session_save_path(dirname(__file__)."/../User");
> ```
>
> Basically, I dont see any file created in that folder.

Does the user as which PHP runs have permissions on that folder? Haven't you got your PHP files sorted in deeper folders, where "(directory)../User" doesn't exist? Have you tried echoing the path to see where it points? Have you tried manually writing a file there? What about using `realpath()`?

> Also when I do this:
>
> ```
> $id=session_id();
> ```
>
> I get id=0;

That's a symptom. Your session doesn't start, so you can't get a session ID.

> $os=$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'];
>   I am trying to get the operating system and I get nothing.

What **do** you get? Tried `var_dump($os)`?

> and when I try to do this: $browser= $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; I get weird browser.
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2

That "Weird Browser" is Chrome 15. What's weird about that?

And please enable error reporting since I'm sure there'll be a few hints there.

Comment: It gives me this as browser variable: browser:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2 ,,, about that server software I solved it. Why the session doesnt start..should I just start it manually?     sorry correction I did this: session.auto_start = 1 on php

Comment: @WithFlyingColors please try to read my whole answer. Your session cannot (auto)start if the session files cannot be written. If you remove all session code and settings, and simply call `session_start()`, do you get a session ID?

Comment: it also gives me this: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() //not sure if it is related..but the session does start

Comment: @WithFlyingColors then the session is started from somewhere else (an include for example), or you didn't put `session.auto_start = 0` in the right php.ini.

Comment: I resolved the mistake of ignoring session start...I still cant figure out how do I set the session auto start to work!?!?

Comment: @WithFlyingColors That depends on what you're doing. If you want to test whether `session_start()` does work, you want session.auto_start to be on 0 (off).